# How to get auto-height from position: absolute element?

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with a deepness of 3. I want to have the 2nd layer left, and the 3rd layer right in a dropdown.

The 3rd layer needs to be absolute positioned otherwise it won't fit to the left of the 2nd layer, but while positioning absolute the height won't go with the absolute-positioned `<ul>`. It only reaches the two 2nd layer-`<li>`-height.

Snippet:

```css
#main_navigation {
  background-color: #006600;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#main_navigation ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#main_navigation>nav>ul>li {
  background: none;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -3px;
  line-height: inherit;
  border-left: 1px solid #6bb36b;
  position: static;
}
#main_navigation>nav>ul>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  transition: background-color ease-in-out 0.46s;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
#main_navigation>nav>ul>li:hover>a, #main_navigation #navigation>ul>li:focus>a {
  background-color: #6bb36b;
  transition: background-color ease-in-out 0.35s;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#main_navigation>nav>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown {
  top: 300%;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  background: none;
  background-color: #006600;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px 0px #333;
  border-top: 2px solid #6bb36b;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #081a08;
  transition: all ease-out 0.45s;
}
#main_navigation>nav>ul>li.dropdown_parent:hover>ul.dropdown, #main_navigation>nav>ul>li.dropdown_parent:focus>ul.dropdown {
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all ease-in 0.35s;
}
#main_navigation>nav>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}
#main_navigation>nav>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent>ul.child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
#main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a:not(.childtrigger) {
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
#main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a:not(.childtrigger):hover, #main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li>li.parent a:not(.childtrigger):focus, #main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent.active a:not(.childtrigger) {
  background-color: #6bb36b;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
#main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a.childtrigger {
  background: rgba(3, 2, 1, 0);
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
#main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a.childtrigger:after {
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  right: 23px;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
#main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a.childtrigger:hover, #main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a.childtrigger:focus {
  background-color: #6bb36b;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
#main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a.childtrigger:hover:after, #main_navigation>#navigation>ul>li.dropdown_parent>ul.dropdown>li.parent a.childtrigger:focus:after {
  border-color: #fff;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_navigation">
  <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown_parent active">
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li class="parent">
            <a class="childtrigger"></a>
            <a href="#">Submenuparent</a>
            <ul class="child">
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="parent">
            <a class="childtrigger"></a>
            <a href="#">Submenuparent 2</a>
            <ul class="child">
              <li><a href="#">Bla 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bla 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

And the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u5gwqzfo/

This is how it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR0Y4.jpg

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Absolute positioning works as this. If you change the `<ul>` to position relative all your dropdown's height will match, but you need some few adjusts to achieve completely what you need. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/u5gwqzfo/1/ . You need to put on top the arrows and the submenus, and you'll get it!

Comment: but then the 2nd layer-<li> will have a huge height which it doesn't need.

Comment: But that's not what you ask? Occupy the entire height to show fine the menu?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pqraNlX.jpg added screenshot to what it SHOULD look like to the question as well. the right side should determine the max height of the complete dropdown. but not the height of the parent-<li>s

Comment: Still thinking you can achieve this with relative positioning, with absolute positioning will be not dynamic since you need to know the exact height to set it, and with relative all will be dynamic, growing up or down when the flow needs.

Comment: but how? i'm trying for ages now. approximately 8-9 hours and i don't get it..

Comment: Reading better the code, I think the problem is in the HTML, is fine to make dropdown pure-css, but your screenshot shows two different things separately. Maybe there is a way to make it pure-css without changing your html structure, but I can't think about it right now. Have no idea in this moment, sorry, but I came back if I imagine something that could work.

Comment: i had an alternative with other markup but that wouldn't fit the requirement from the backend-developer for his typo3-system

Comment: I can suggest you to make the left pane all in a `<ul>`and the right pane have each `<ul>` for each child section, so you can show and hide the related child from the left pane something like `.menu[target=first] ~ .submenu.first { display : block } .menu[target=second] ~ .submenu.second { display : block }`. So your markup will be separated left from right, but your functionality still persists with pure-css with no javascript. This way allows you to write the right pane with position relative. This fits with your requirements?

Comment: it's not about the funcionality. that already workes via jQuery click/and mouseoveron the arrow. but i need the markup to be more "classic" (ul>li>ul>li) - nested way, so it's easier to render through typo3. but it should still look like on the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't size the .parent with the absolutely positioned .child as absolute positioning removes the element from the box model.

If you're tied to this markup structure you can use javascript to set the height of the .dropdown to be the same as the height of the .child

(I used jquery)

something like :

```
$(".parent").hover(function() {
    x = $(this).find(".child").height();
$(this).parent('.dropdown').css({
    'height': x + 'px'
   });
 }, function() {
  $(this).parent('.dropdown').css({
    'height': 'auto'
  });
});
```

I here's (a very janky) pen to demonstrate what I mean.
http://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/YWwpgJ

Comment: i actually thought about this already and it seems to be the only solution i came up with as well.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal, but if the design is set in stone, and the markup is inflexible if you add a timeout, and change the transition on the menu to be up> down it'll fly.